# iOS UIView is not updated immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

When I do UI updates from the main thread, they do not seem to take effect straight away. That is, the changes do not appear immediately on screen.

Here is a simplified version of the code I'm running:

```
- (void) do_ui_update {
    // UI update here that does not appear immediately
}

- (void) some_time_consuming_function {
    // line 1
    // line 2
    // ...
    // line n
}

- (void) function_that_runs_in_main_thread {
    [self RUN_ON_UI_THREAD:^{
        [self do_ui_update];

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [self some_time_consuming_function];
        });
    }];
}

- (void) RUN_ON_UI_THREAD:(dispatch_block_t)block 
{
    if ([NSThread isMainThread])
        block();
    else
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
}
```

When I debug setting breakpoints at each line in `some_time_consuming_function`, sometimes the UI updates appear on screen when the debugger hits line 2, sometime line 3, and so on.

So my question is:
How can I make the UI updates appear on screen before the very first line of `some_time_consuming_function` is reached?

Comment: This sounds to me like `function_that_runs_in_main_thread` isn't always on the main thread. If you set a break point on `[self do_ui_update]` is it on the main thread 100% of the time?

Comment: can u show code that runs the function_that_runs_in_main_thread on main thread ?

Comment: I suspect this is related to the run-loop.  The view will only be updated at the end of the runloop.  It's probably best to have `some_time_consuming_function` running in a background thread to solve this.

Comment: You sure you are on the main thread ? maybe you can add a `dispatch` to be sure to be on main thread just to be sure. Or add some code otherwise we can't help much here

Comment: Thank you for the comments. For those who are concerned about whether or not `function_that_runs_in_main_thread` does indeed run in the main thread, I've edited my code to reflect this.

Comment: @bradkratky I don't need to call setNeedsDisplay since I'm not doing any custom drawings, just adding/removing subviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispatch the background dispatch to the next main loop iteration:

```
-(void) function_that_runs_in_main_thread {
    [self do_ui_update];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // All pending UI updates are now completed
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [self some_time_consuming_function];
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mats. This does work. However, I'm trying to understand *why* it works. Is it because previously I was starting an asynchronous process that could start before the main run loop is finished with UI updates, whereas now, the async process is added to main queue which is serial, and therefore guarantees UI updates finishing first?

Comment: Yes. I don’t remember if it is actually documented anywhere, but it has always worked this way.